# Query different number of posts with different formats in one go

Tags: wp-query, post-formats

I want to output 7 latest status posts and 5 latest aside posts in one go (they should be sorted in one list from latest to earliest). But I don't understand how to write such a WP_Tax_Query. I've tried the following and it didn't work as intended:

```
$args = array(
'relation' => 'AND',
array(
'post_format' => 'post-format-status',
'posts_per_page' => 7,
),
array(
'post_format' => 'post-format-aside',
'posts_per_page' => 5,
)
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $q->have_posts() ) { 
while ( $q->have_posts() ) { $q->the_post(); the_title(); }
wp_reset_postdata();}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn’t possible in one query. You can’t set posts per page for individual taxonomy queries.

You can either query 12 status or aside posts together:

```
array(
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'post-format-status', 'post-format-aside' ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Or perform separate queries with `get_posts()` with the desired number for each, merging the results, then sorting the merged results by date:

```
// Get statuses.
$statuses = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 7,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'post-format-status',
        ),
    ),
) );

// Get asides.
$asides = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'post-format-aside',
        ),
    ),
) );

// Merge results.
$posts = array_merge( $statuses, $asides );

// Sort results by comparing the dates.
uasort( $posts, function( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime( $b->post_date ) - strtotime( $a->post_date );
} );

global $post;

foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );

endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();
```